# Passing from Activity2 to Activity1 and then again reflecting changes from Activity 1 to Activity 2

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview

I've 2 activities, `Activity1` and `Activity2`.

In Activity1 i've a `EdiText` and `ImageView`. When button is clicked Activity2 is started.

In Activity2 i've a listview. It contains `Image` and `TextView`.

I have displayed the data retrieved from listview image and textview in Activity2 in the imageview and editext resp in Activity1 . Now i made some changes in the editext and imageview in Activity1 and I need to pass this changes again to the listview image and text in Activity 2.

can someone help me with the code to make this work?

Comment: Now, you have stated what you need. Please show some releavant code you have been working on. It could help us who are trying to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better idea is to use startActivityForResult.

It similar problem to this:
[How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result)

Answer (score 0):

In your current activity1, create an intent

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
i.putExtra(key, value);
startActivity(i);
```

then in the other activity2, retrieve those values.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
if(extras !=null) {
    String value = extras.getString(key);
}
```